# Laravel mix not loading tailwind

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I'm following this tutorial in setting up tailwind with laravel mix: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel#mix

I've done all the steps.

Here's my `tailwind.config.js` contents:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I've also created `resources/css/dashboard.css` file, here are the contents:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I've updated my webpack file as well:

```js
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .postCss("resources/css/dashboard.css", "public/css", [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .extract()
    .vue(3);
```

And imported `resources/css/dashboard.css` into my main layout file:

```
<link href="{{ mix('/css/dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also added some tailwind classes in my `resources/js/Pages/Users/Patients/Dashboard.vue` component (I'm using vue3):

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
</h1>
```

Unfortunately, it seems the tailwind styles are not working properly:
[image: dashboard not displaying tailwind classes]

If I open network, I see that the `dashboard.css` file is loaded correctly

[image: dashboard file loaded correctly]

Sadly, didn't have any luck. What seems to be the problem here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you make changes on the CSS file?

Comment: Why would you 'import' the dashboard.css file to a link ?
You should add the @tailwind directives to your ./resources/css/app.css file instead of creating a new dashboard.css file.

Comment: @Memristor not sure what do you mean by that.

Comment: @Joeri I don't have resources/css/app.css , my dashboard.css acts like app.css, I just renamed it

Comment: @zlatan Just to test it out, could you remove `.extract()` from `mix`? Also, if you open the compiled `.css` file, do you have a lot of stuff? If you do a search and look for `text-3xl`, is the class in the compiled file (so we check that tailwind is at least being compiled in there)?

Comment: @matiaslauriti that's a good suggestion. I will try that now. And for the second question, seems like the file was not compiled at all, the contents were just copy/pasted to another location, as you can see in the last image.